# Fetch a checkbox list and get them in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I'm fetching values from a checkbox list and would like to get them in mysql, just like the following sql query shows:

```
 <form action="index2.php" method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" alt="Checkbox" value="one">One
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" alt="Checkbox" value="two">Two
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" alt="Checkbox" value="three">Three
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    <?php
    if(!empty($_GET['check_list'])) 
    {
    foreach($_GET['check_list'] as $check) 
    {  
    $ids = implode(',', $check); 
    echo $ids;
    }
    }

    $sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE activity IN($ids)";

    I've tried with array(), implode(), explode()...
    Nothing works.
    this is a simplified code: I did not put the code against injection.
    Can anybody be of help. Thanks :)

    ?>
```

Can anybody be of help? Thanks very much in advance :)

Comment: What is the issue? Is `$ids` empty? Does it contain the wrong values? Is the code run at all?

Comment: Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Comment: with $_GET: values ok-> ex: onetwothree (all attached)

Comment: What do you get from `var_dump($_GET['check_list'])` ?

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "one" [1]=> string(3) "two" }

Comment: Then you just need to `implode(',', $_GET['check_list'])` to get a comma-separated list that you can pass into `IN`. Just remember to validate your data (you say you're already doing this, which is good!); and you'll need logic to handle the case where `$_GET['check_list']` is empty.

Comment: Feel free to add your working code as an answer, and accept it when you can!